# Mysql order by date last 24hours and top 1 else by id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Basically i have products witch might have top = 1 or top 0, i need to order by top, where top = 1 and created_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) and than order by id.

At the moment i have

```
    $products = Products::where('buy', '0')
        ->where('status', '1')
        ->where('sold', '0')
        ->where('deleted', '0')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('CASE WHEN `created_at` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `top` = 1 THEN `top` ELSE `id` END'), 'desc')
        ->limit(12, 0)
        ->get();
```

Unfortunately it is not working. Not sure, maybe i'm doing it totally wrong?

Comment: What about this is not working? Can you share the DB structure? I generated the following query based on this syntax: SELECT * from `18969545` WHERE buy = 0 AND status = 1 AND sold = 0 AND deleted = 0 ORDER BY CASE WHEN `created_at` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `top` = 1 THEN `top` ELSE `id` END desc;

Comment: What's the expected result? What's the result you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can not toggle the ORDER BY statement !**
it' impbased on a value.
It is simply impossible to do that and also useless because it is then sorted by the last comparison value.

if the last row matches,

If `created_at < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ...` then

`ORDER BY top desc`
and otherwise .
`ORDER BY id desc`

This means the whole dataset is re-sorted.

With a trick you can get what you want.

we assume

DATE_SUB(now()) == 2013-09-24 06:15:44.657

the sample table

```
ID      top     created_at
1       1       2013-09-20 18:21:15.123     
2       0       2013-09-18 08:15:15.123 
3       1       2013-09-17 09:15:15.123 
4       1       2013-09-23 15:11:15.123 
5       0       2013-09-21 22:18:15.123 
6       0       2013-09-22 22:45:15.123 
7       1       2013-09-23 18:24:15.123 
8       1       2013-09-22 23:21:15.123 
9       0       2013-09-24 01:07:15.123 
10      1       2013-09-24 02:24:15.123
```

what you want to have as a result :

```
10      1       2013-09-24 02:24:15.123 
7       1       2013-09-23 18:24:15.123 
4       1       2013-09-23 15:11:15.123 
9       0       2013-09-24 01:07:15.123 
8       1       2013-09-22 23:21:15.123 
6       0       2013-09-22 22:45:15.123 
5       0       2013-09-21 22:18:15.123 
3       1       2013-09-17 09:15:15.123     
2       0       2013-09-18 08:15:15.123     
1       1       2013-09-20 18:21:15.123
```

the select to test in a mysql editor / manager
Note: *10000 must be greater than the greatest ID in the table
Is ok until `ID` < 9999 !

```
SELECT ID, top, created_at,
 CASE WHEN `created_at` < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
 AND `top` = 1 THEN `ID` *10000 ELSE `ID` END as sortfield FROM products
 ORDER BY sortfield DESC;
```

the select

```
    ->select(array('ID', 'top', 'created_at',
      DB::raw('CASE WHEN `created_at` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
      AND `top` = 1 THEN `ID` *10000 ELSE `ID` END as sortfield')))
    ->where('buy', '0')
    ->where('status', '1')
    ->where('sold', '0')
    ->where('deleted', '0')
    ->orderBy('sortfield' , 'desc')
    ->limit(12, 0)
    ->get();
```

result:

```
ID      top     created_at                  sortfield
10      1       2013-09-24 02:24:15.123     100000
7       1       2013-09-23 18:24:15.123      70000
4       1       2013-09-23 15:11:15.123      40000
9       0       2013-09-24 01:07:15.123     9
8       1       2013-09-22 23:21:15.123     8
6       0       2013-09-22 22:45:15.123     6
5       0       2013-09-21 22:18:15.123     5
3       1       2013-09-17 09:15:15.123     3
2       0       2013-09-18 08:15:15.123     2
1       1       2013-09-20 18:21:15.123     1
```

I know it does not look as elegant, but you can also just set the values ​​to `1` and `0`
 .

```
 ... AND `top` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as sortfield ...
```

Comment: Yeah - this one works for me - maybe there is some other way? Anyway thx ;)

Comment: I know it does not look as elegant, but you can also just set the values ​​to `1`  and `0`.